# Excel If statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a file that looks like this:

```
col hea der s   row
A   0   0   0   0
C   1   2   1   0
N   3   2   3   5
```

I want to write an if statement that says
if any of the values in cells D2, G2, J2 or M2 are greater than or equal to 5, count one.
ie:

```
cel D2  G2  J2  M2
col hea der s  row  count
A   0   4   0   0       0
C   1   5   1   0       1
N   10  2   3   5       2
```

I can't get the logic right at all, so I have a feeling that there is a less complicated way to do it. This is what I have so far:

```
IF(D2>=5, 1, 0, IF(AND(G2>=5, 2, 0), IF(AND(J2>=5, 3, 0), IF(AND(M2>=5, 4, 0)))))
```

But this is obviously nowhere close to what I need. It only will tell you if all 4 are there, not anything else. 
The only way I can figure this is some horrifyingly long if statement.
Can anyone point me in a better direction?

Comment: countifs might work here... but I've been playing around with it to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I provided this in a comment, it will accomplish the task you're looking for:

```
=SUM(D2>=5,G2>=5,J2>=5,M2>=5)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would have told you to use `COUNTIF` if you had a continuous range, but, I guess you can do:

```
=--(D2>=5)+--(G2>=5)+--(J2>=5)+--(M2>=5)
```

`(D2>=5)` gives either true or false, and adding `--` at the front makes it into 1 or 0.

Adding all those together gives you the count you're looking for :)

You can use:

```
=(D2>=5)+(G2>=5)+(J2>=5)+(M2>=5)
```

As well, but I just can't get around adding 'true' and 'false', not yet anyway!

Comment: There's no need for all the `--` because you're adding the resulting boolean values together anyway. `=(D2>=5)+(G2>=5)+(J2>=5)+(M2>=5)`

Comment: @pnuts You can drop the `--` as well, I guess I should ^^;

Comment: @tigeravatar Good point. I sometimes like to see things as number as opposed to true/false ^^;

Comment: Here's another way to write it using, SUM so that you don't have to duplicate parentheses: `=SUM(D2>=5,G2>=5,J2>=5,M2>=5)`

Comment: @tigeravatar Smooth! You could probably add that as answer!